# Cant disconnect from xero using xero.disconnect

Tags: node.js, xero-api

Im using AdonisJs as my Node Framework, the xeroclient config works perfectly, I can extract details that I need.

I just cant disconnect, as I saw in their [sample app](https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-node-oauth2-app/blob/master/src/app.ts#L268) we just have to call xero.disconnect, yet i am receiving an error `xero.disconnect is not a function`

im using the xero-node npm package

```
const xeroNode = require('xero-node')

const xero = new xeroNode.XeroClient({
  clientId: Config.get('xero.client_id'),
  clientSecret: Config.get('xero.client_secret'),
  redirectUris: [Config.get('xero.redirectUri')],
  scopes: Config.get('xero.scopes').split(" ")
})

async disconnect ({ response, session }) {
   ...
   await xero.disconnect(xero.tenantIds[0])
   ...
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that looks incorrect is the parameter you are passing to the function. That should actually be the connection object's ID not the tenantId itself: `await xero.disconnect(xero.tenants[0].id)`

But other than that can you elaborate the package version you are using? I've just mimicked everything about how you are importing and setting up client, so it's unclear why the disconnect function is not available. Please ensure you are using the most recent version 4.6.0 - the following just worked for me after I successfully got my access token back from the /callback flow.

Setup:

```
const xeroNode = require('xero-node')

const xero = new xeroNode.XeroClient({
    clientId: client_id,
    clientSecret: client_secret,
    redirectUris: [redirectUrl],
    scopes: scopes.split(' '),
});
```

/connect

```
const consentUrl: = await xero.buildConsentUrl();
```

/callback

```
const tokenSet = await xero.apiCallback(returning_url);
await xero.updateTenants();
```

/disconnect

```
const connection = xero.tenants[0]

await xero.disconnect(connection.id)
```

If you can post/log some more info can get this sorted for you!